# access to a variable in constructor function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why we can't access a variable defined in a constructor function. Below is the given condition.

```
    var getEmployee = function(name){
                var usrId = 9;
                this.name = name;
            }
    var emp = new getEmployee("Karlie Kloss");
    console.log(emp.usrId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable `usrId`is declared with `var`: so it is not "attached" to the object.

To do so, you have to use `this` instead of `var`, like this:

```
var getEmployee = function(name) {
    this.usrId = 9;
    this.name = name;
}

var emp = new getEmployee("Karlie Kloss");
console.log(emp.usrId);
```

The keyword `var` makes the varaible scoped to the parent "top-block" (e.g. function), so it is not visible outside it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a local variable. Variable has a scope. As you have defined variable in function (using var userId). So its scope has limited to its function. you can't access that variable outside that function.Use this instead of var.

```
var getEmployee = function(name) {
    this.usrId = 9;
    this.name = name;
}

var emp = new getEmployee("Karlie Kloss");
console.log(emp.usrId);
```

You can study about variable scope here:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/variable-scope-javascript